# Bug in PANDAS - ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filtering, division

I found a bug in PANDAS yesterday.
I found also a workaround but I'd like team to work on it and solve it.

I have a dataframe with two columns and I need to make division between column 'A' and column 'B'.
If in column 'B' there is a 'zero' the only way to make it is to create a temporary dataframe filtered with 'B != 0' and then proceed with division creating column 'C'
There is no way to generate it directly.

df is dataframe with column "A" and "B"

Below workround works

```
df_temporary = df.loc[df['B'] != 0, ['A','B']]
df_temporary['C'] = df['A']/df['B']
```

Below direct process does not work

```
df.loc[df['B']!= 0, ['C']] = df['A']/df['B']
```

The last generate `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`

Comment: Help us understand how it is a bug? Is it already listed here?  
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not bug, because you not filter column `B`, so there is division by `0`.

You need filter `B` column like:

```
 df['C'] = df['A']/df.loc[df['B']!= 0, 'B']
```

If need filter both `A, B` use:

```
 df['C'] = df.loc[df['A']!= 0, 'A']/df.loc[df['B']!= 0, 'B']
```